# How to run batch file without admin privillege?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I am newbie to batch file script.I have created simple windows bat file.The problem is bat file run only if the user has admin privilege.But i want to run this batch file for all users like normal users,standard users and guest etc.I have used windows 7.

```
Access is denied.
[2013-09-18 09:55:07] [error] Unable to open the Service Manager
[2013-09-18 09:55:07] [error] Access is denied.
[2013-09-18 09:55:07] [error] Access is denied.
Access is denied.
Failed to install service
```

Is possible run windows bat file  for all users?

Comment: What is the error you are getting when running it as a non admin?

Comment: I have added the error message when running it as a non admin

Comment: Check effective permission of user account to the bat and files called, also is this computer on a domain or just a home PC

Comment: what you mean "check effective permission of user account" but my question no need to check user privilege×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Comment: Google effective permissions to long for a comment, what is the batch file doing or can you post source? It could be calling a executable that is stopping it?

Answer (score 5):

Running a batch file with administrative privileges requires your intervention. Running a batch file without is accomplished by default. However, there are several exceptions and possible issues.

Your batch file may include commands that simply fail without elevation, for example writing to the Program Files directory. This is a common issue and the error messages suggest you are experiencing a problem of this kind. Apparently, the batch file either tries to create a service through the service manager, or launches an external program to do this. The batch file does run without administrative privileges, but does not work as intended.

This is normal behaviour. The service manager is largely off limits to normal users. The reason you're getting 'access denied' messages is because access is (correctly) denied. Security settings for access to services can be altered, but I would strongly advise against doing so.

If what your batch file is designed for ought to work without elevation, then rewrite it to avoid using the service manager. If that is somehow infeasable, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436558/start-stop-a-windows-service-from-a-non-administrator-user-account) has a ton of information about using services without administrative privileges.